# Chrome Extension 'Package is Invalid' error on Linux installs

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chromebook

I recently published my extension publicly on the Chrome Web Store and new users have started installing it. Unfortunately about half of new installs error out with this error:

> Package is Invalid. Details: 'Could not load icon
> 'images/BrainTool128.png' specified in 'icons'.'.

The relevant manifest section looks like this:

```
"icons": {
  "16": "images/BrainTool16.png",
  "32": "images/BrainTool32.png",
  "48": "images/BrainTool48.png",
  "128": "images/BrainTool128.png"
},
```

The 128x128 image is there under /images, its working for many users and I can't reproduce. I've previously had developer dashboard throw me errors when an image was incorrect in some way (wrong size etc) and so assumed it was validating the package. Also I'm only packaging the extension contents not any containing folders (as was the issue w previous questions).

This is very frustrating given that I'm just starting to get some actual real users for my app. Any help appreciated.

PS The extension is here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/braintool/fialfmcgpibjgdoeodaondepigiiddio

Update: It appears that this is only an issue for Chromebook and Linux users.

Answer (score 0):

This was my error :-(

The actual file was there but was named Braintool128.png (lower case t), so the error message was correct. Its confusing that this was not caught on package verification and in fact the extension worked fine for everyone but Linux/Chromium users.